# LibBDX create a tail when the object is moved

Tags: libgdx, animation, shadows, motion

I am looking for a way to implement in my game a kind of shadow/tail which will be displayed after the object is moved. Should I use animation? If yes how? Here an example:

[image]

Comment: usually you use some ParticleEmitters. LibGDX already has one.

Comment: @BenediktS.Vogler Thank you so much! I didn't know it!

Answer (score 1):

I used [ParticleEditor](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/2D-Particle-Editor) to create this:

[image: Basic Fire Particle]

This is the code:

```
package com.gamefromscratch;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.ParticleEffect;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;

public class Particles extends ApplicationAdapter {
   SpriteBatch batch;
   ParticleEffect pe;

   @Override
   public void create () {
      batch = new SpriteBatch();

      pe = new ParticleEffect();
      pe.load(Gdx.files.internal("Particles.party"),Gdx.files.internal(""));
      pe.getEmitters().first().setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2);
      pe.start();
   }

   @Override
   public void render () {
      Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
      Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

      pe.update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
      batch.begin();
      pe.draw(batch);
      batch.end();
      if (pe.isComplete())
         pe.reset();
   }
}
```

This is a basic fire that can be used (for example) in any car, simulating turbo. You can edit create something more specific with the ParticleEditor.